# UPDATE QUERY Change text PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I am trying to update a database table, by cursing out the bad words here is my query to, but I am not too sure how to do it here is my code

```
$query2 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT texte FROM commentaires");
$query2->execute();
$res2 = $query2->fetchAll();
foreach($res2 as $result) {
    $originaltext = $result["texte"];
    $newtext = grosmots($result["texte"]);
    $query2 = $bdd->prepare("UPDATE commentaires SET texte = {$newtext} WHERE texte = :oldtext");
    $query2->bindValue(":oldtext", $originaltext);
    $query2->execute();
}
 print '<pre>';
    print_r($res2);
    print '</pre>';;
```

Comment: What `grosmots` function does ?

Comment: Add `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: It french for bad words, all it does is str_ireplace the badword by -*****- all I want to do is update the table rowsand replace all the bad words with this -*****-. @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: I added that @Fred-ii- No I get an error here it is: `code
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<b>!@*$#</b> LIDEKSLS WHERE texte = 'HASTAGE LIDEKSLS'' at line 1' 
/antigrosmots.php(25): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /antigrosmots.php on line 25
`

Comment: It has something to do with `{$newtext}` then. You should add another bind for that, or use a different quoting method. Or, try `SET texte = '".$newtext."'`

Comment: Great, shall I make that an answer?

Comment: Yes as you please. @Fred-ii- :) Have a good day.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer I've given you below as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You missed quoting the $newtext variable.

But as you are using PDO you should avoid putting a variable inside the query, seems that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. I suggest the following change:

```
$statement = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE commentaires SET texte = :newtext WHERE texte = :oldtext;');
$statement->bindValue(":newtext", $newtext);
$statement->bindValue(":oldtext", $originaltext);
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you're using `SET texte = {$newtext}`

MySQL will complain about that.

Modify your query so that it reads as:

```
SET texte = '".$newtext."'
```

Or, you can use another bind for it.

---

Add `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.